# Anyone knows a wysiwyg editor for symfony 4?

Tags: php, wysiwyg, symfony4

I am a beginner in Symfony and I started by Symfony 4. I'm looking for a text editor. I've already tried to use CKEditor and Froala but they work with Symfony 3. Thus my question is:

Anyone knows a WYSIWYG editor for Symfony 4?

Also, it's the first I used this kind of component.
The data I would like the editor handle is images and text with different font styles.

Thanks in advance to those who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony is request-response framework it will generate html and you can handle this html with any Ckeditor version